# Font tag and word spacing issue

Tags: css

To start: I 100% understand that the font tag is depresiated and should not be used. I'd love to meet the terrible person who did this to me, trust me :)

I have a large CMS system with custom entries that use:

```
<span>
    <font size="5">
        This is the long sentence that gives me a problem every time.
    </font>
</span>
```

Now what is happening is I'm getting random spacing between words (like between This and Is, it's twice as big as the space between gives and me). I've tried using letter-spacing -0.1em, but that really screws up other areas of the site. I would love to use text-align to fix it, but it's not working.

How can I control the word spacing/alignment for JUST the font tag. Messing with the span tags, unless there's a way that won't mess with my grandfathered content, isn't an option it appears.

Thanks a ton

Comment: Try with `font{padding:0;margin:0;}`

Comment: Ha! I needed to explicitly declare the display:block for the tag. For whatever reason, it wasn't registering the parent's display.

Comment: There was no description of the problem that would make it possible to reproduce it; the issue was clearly caused by something external to the code posted. So we cannot know what the problem really was, or how it was solved.

Comment: I think that's a little hasty. I have you a sample code (instead of the actual wording, I put fake working). I explained what I used. And clearly the issue was understandable because the gentleman below figured out my issue in about 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a reset of typographic styles:

```
font {
    padding: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: block;
}
```

The property `display` is not inherited by default. You need to set it explicitly.

Comment: This was exactly it. I didn't realize the display needed to be explicity called.